# Create a new column - Only assign last value by group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Supposing I have the following dataframe:

```
        date    sku        Q     f   
0   2019-10-23  1101692 10.000  001 
1   2019-10-24  1101692 10.000  002 
2   2019-10-23  1101692 15.000  007 
3   2019-10-22  1101692 -10.000 100 
4   2019-10-23  1101692 -10.000 100 
5   2019-10-23  1101692 -15.000 100 
6   2019-10-21  1101692 600.000 100
```

Using this groupby command to get the last value by group:

```
df.groupby(['sku', 'f']).last()
```

I got:

```
              data        q 
sku      f          
1101692 001 2019-10-23  10.000  
        002 2019-10-24  10.000  
        007 2019-10-23  15.000  
        100 2019-10-21  600.000
```

I am trying to create a new column that will have the 'q' column values (last values of each group).

**Expected output:**

```
         date    sku        Q     f  New_column 
0   2019-10-23  1101692 10.000  001    10.000
1   2019-10-24  1101692 10.000  002    10.000
2   2019-10-23  1101692 15.000  007    15.000
3   2019-10-22  1101692 -10.000 100     NaN
4   2019-10-23  1101692 -10.000 100     NaN
5   2019-10-23  1101692 -15.000 100     NaN
6   2019-10-21  1101692 600.000 100    600.000
```

What is a good approach to create this new column. I have tried using iloc, but it seems trick.

Then I tried to use

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby(['sku', 'f'])['q'].apply(lambda x: x.index[0])
```

but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need `groupby()` here, you can just do:

```
df['new_col'] = df['Q'].mask(df.duplicated(['sku', 'f'], keep='last'))
```

Output:

```
         date      sku      Q    f  new_col
0  2019-10-23  1101692   10.0    1     10.0
1  2019-10-24  1101692   10.0    2     10.0
2  2019-10-23  1101692   15.0    7     15.0
3  2019-10-22  1101692  -10.0  100      NaN
4  2019-10-23  1101692  -10.0  100      NaN
5  2019-10-23  1101692  -15.0  100      NaN
6  2019-10-21  1101692  600.0  100    600.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to assign the `df` back is through `merge`

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['sku', 'f'], as_index=False).last().rename(columns={'Q':'q'}), 
         on=['sku', 'f', 'date'], 
         how='outer')
```

---

```
         date      sku      Q    f      q
0  2019-10-23  1101692   10.0    1   10.0
1  2019-10-24  1101692   10.0    2   10.0
2  2019-10-23  1101692   15.0    7   15.0
3  2019-10-22  1101692  -10.0  100    NaN
4  2019-10-23  1101692  -10.0  100    NaN
5  2019-10-23  1101692  -15.0  100    NaN
6  2019-10-21  1101692  600.0  100  600.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use callable with `loc`

```
df['New_column'] = df.loc[lambda x: x.groupby(['sku', 'f']).tail(1).index, 'Q']

Out[581]:
         date      sku      Q    f  New_column
0  2019-10-23  1101692   10.0    1        10.0
1  2019-10-24  1101692   10.0    2        10.0
2  2019-10-23  1101692   15.0    7        15.0
3  2019-10-22  1101692  -10.0  100         NaN
4  2019-10-23  1101692  -10.0  100         NaN
5  2019-10-23  1101692  -15.0  100         NaN
6  2019-10-21  1101692  600.0  100       600.0
```

---

Note: if you don't like callable, you may try direct `df` groupby as:  `df.loc[df.groupby(['sku', 'f']).tail(1).index, 'Q']`